# grails textfield with formatDate

Tags: datetime, grails, format, textfield, date-formatting

I have the following textfield in my gsp page that does not work as expected:

```
<g:textField name="startTime"
     value="${formatDate(date: occurrenceStart ? new Instant(occurrenceStart).toDate() : eventInstance?.startTime, format: 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a')}"
     class="datetime" />
```

I'm using the source code found [here](http://www.craigburke.com/post/44771880610/creating-google-calendar-in-grails-part-1-the-model), but each time I select a date and time, the date is shown as MM/dd/yyyy. Where is the place in which I need to change the format?

EDIT:
Usually I use Mozilla Firefox to test my project. If I use Google Chrome browser, I have the following formatting date(choosing the 12th of January 2014, 5:00 AM) after the change suggested in Adavis answer:

12/January/20142014 hh:01 a 05:00 am

If I remove the code added, I have the same behaviour described above, with formatting MM/dd/yyyy

Comment: I tried your code above with "<g:textField name="startTime" value="${formatDate(date: new Date(), format: 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a')}"/>" and it works. maybe its your CSS that is converting to MM/dd/yyyy?

Comment: The fact is that my css (created by me in project) has nothing about this field. Can you try to have a look at the code from which I've taken this field (as linked in my post)? Are you sure that it depends on CSS and not on Javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with the following code:

```
function setupDatePickers() {
$.datepicker.setDefaults({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
});
$("input.datetime").datetimepicker({
    ampm: true,
    stepMinute: 15
});
```

}

Answer (score 1):

In this file: https://github.com/craigburke/google-calendar-grails/blob/master/web-app/js/calendar.js, line 60, in *setupDatePickers()*, you need to add your date format to the default options of *datetimepicker*.  See below...

```
function setupDatePickers() {
    $("input.datetime").datetimepicker({
        ampm: true,
        stepMinute: 15,
        dateFormat: 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a'
    });
}
```

Comment: I've tried to edit code as you have suggested, but it does not change anything. I continue to see the format MM/dd/yyyy

Comment: If that's not working for you, put a breakpoint in your code in the feilds' onchange method of the javascript and see what's happening.